# How to test C++ modules with godbolt (compiler explorer)?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules, compiler-explorer

In order to ask questions about or demonstrate bugs/features with self-written modules in C++20, it would be great to be able to use [Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

**Example:**

test.cpp (module test):

```
export module test;

export template<typename T>
void do_something(const T&)
{
}
```

Compile with `clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -c -Xclang -emit-module-interface -o test.pcm test.cpp`

main.cpp:

```
import test;

int main() {
    do_something(7);
}
```

Compile with `clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fimplicit-modules -fimplicit-module-maps -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cpp`

**Q: Is there a way to do this with compiler explorer?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you cannot. A typical modules example needs multiple source files. Eg. in your case, main.cpp & test.cpp. This is not currently supported in GodBolt.
I tried building using the raw github content on Godbolt. But it does not work. I have opened this [request](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/2166).
Also see this ongoing [request](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/1892) which seemingly is under process.

Comment: @AfulMehra looks like the first request link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out..Corrected link by removing the fullstop at end. Here's the link again anyway - https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/2166.

Comment: For today problem [is not multiple sources](https://godbolt.org/z/1KzMesx93), but more [like missing per-compiled modules](https://godbolt.org/z/s1erjzKeb).

Answer (score 3):

Now we can!! https://godbolt.org/z/1szKxKMP6

With CMake 3.28 just merged in CE, it's even easier!

Comment: Is it possible to also use "import std;" on godbolt? I'm not proficient enough with cmake to know what I might need to edit in order for that to work, but I'd like to try "std::println(isSolid(solidCell));" in main(). Would really appreciate it if you could add that in your link. :-)

Comment: For the moment (2024-03) only msvc seems to have 'import std;' working, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170 but for a godbolt example, lets wait for clang :-)